# excessive space in align environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align

If I want the both sides of an equation to be left-aligned, I can write something like

```
\begin{align*}
&abc &&= very-long-expression\\
&abcde &&= short\\
&a &&=long-expression
\end{align*}
```

which results in the following rendering (I included a line from a paragraph after it to show that it is a double-column environment, if that matters). You can see there is a very large white space between `abcde` and `= short`. How can I remove this space, while still keeping the left hand side and right hand side both left-aligned?

[image: rendering]

Comment: Why are you using that many `&`'s? For this a single `&` in front of every `=` is enough

Comment: `\begin{alignat*}{2}`

Comment: @daleif that will make the left hand side align at the characters "c", "e" and "a" on the three lines, while I want them to align at the leftmost "a".

Comment: @egreg oh that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @zyl1024 that is the normal way to align